# Hibernate and MySql

Tags: hibernate, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to learn Hibernate so I have created a very simple Java project with one table. I have set the primary key to autogenerate the id using strategy=GenerationType.Auto.  Once the table is created through hibernate, i then go into MySql workbench and attempt to populate the table.  I am not supplying the id as I am assuming it will be automatically generated.

At this point I receive an error stating: the field does not have a default value.

So i set up a default value using Hibernate Annotations and then run the SQL Insert statement again and this time it tells me: Duplicate entry for primary key

Because I have not supplied a primary key it is using the default, which I guess makes sense.

What I do not understand is why it is not generating an id automatically.

Things I have tried:
1. Set Global sql_mode=""
2. Apply a default using Hibernate annotations.

```
package com.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ERS_User_Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "int default 0")
    private int user_role_id;


    private String user_role_description;

    public ERS_User_Role(int user_role_id, String user_role_description) {
        super();
        this.user_role_id = user_role_id;
        this.user_role_description = user_role_description;
    }

    public int getUser_role_id() {
        return user_role_id;
    }

    public void setUser_role_id(int user_role_id) {
        this.user_role_id = user_role_id;
    }

    public String getUser_role_description() {
        return user_role_description;
    }

    public void setUser_role_description(String user_role_description) {
        this.user_role_description = user_role_description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ERS_User_Role [user_role_id=" + user_role_id + ", user_role_description=" + user_role_description + "]";
    }

}



DELETE FROM ERS_USER_ROLE;

commit;

INSERT INTO ERS_USER_ROLE (USER_ROLE_DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('Employee');
INSERT INTO ERS_USER_ROLE (USER_ROLE_DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('Manager');
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at you code and [these post on Hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1044852), it seems to be the path to follow :

```
@Column(name="user_role_id", nullable = false, columnDefinition="INT NOT NULL")
private int user_role_id;
```

And set your default value to zero if you want, but if I were you I will not do this. It means you need to provide yourself the id to evince the duplicate ids error you have. If you want to have generated unique identifiers then you don't need to set a default value.

Comment: So i removed the default value but I now back to the error that says no default specified.  I don't understand why an id is not being automatically generated when i try to insert a record.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the strategy to GenerationType.Identity and it is now working as expected.